# How to use a Counter

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a counter controlled while loop. Currently I'm having difficulty getting the counter to increase by 1 for each pass through off the loop.

I set my code to

```
int numberCounter = 0;  // Numbers 0 through 10.        
String head1 = "Number: " + numberCounter;      
String head2 = " Multiplied by 2: " + numberCounter * 2;        
String head3 = " Multiplied by 10:  " + numberCounter * 10;                      
int byTwo;     // Stores the number multiplied by 2.    
int byTen;     // Stores the number multiplied by 10.
final int NUM_LOOPS = 11; // Constant used to control loop.

     // This is the work done in the housekeeping() method
System.out.println("Numbers 0 through 10 multiplied by 2 and by 10" + "\n");
System.out.println(head1 + head2 + "\n");
System.out.println(head1 + head3 + "\n");
while (numberCounter != 10) numberCounter = numberCounter + 1;

System.out.println(head1 + head2 + "\n");
System.out.println(head1 + head3 + "\n");
```

but it just reads the 0 value and exits after one pass.

I expect each pass to add one to the counter, but it seems to stay at 0. I say that because the output reads:

Numbers 0 through 10 multiplied by 2 and by 10

Number: 0 Multiplied by 2: 0

Number: 0 Multiplied by 10:  0

Number: 0 Multiplied by 2: 0

Number: 0 Multiplied by 10:  0

Comment: That should work (provided that `numberCounter` doesn't start with the value 10), you need to show us more of your code to see what goes wrong.

Comment: That code should work. What do you mean "it just reads the 0 value"?

Comment: What makes you think that "*but it just reads the 0 value and exits after one pass*"? Use [edit] option to clarify your question.

Comment: Isn't this the exact use-case for a `for` loop?

Comment: It seems you are under impression that when you have `String head1 = "Number: " + numberCounter;` and later you change value of `numberCounter` then data held by `head1` should also *change/update*. That is not true. Value of string is decided *at time of its creation* and never changes. Just like when you have `int a =1;` and later you write `int b = a;` your `b` will hold its own copy of value 1 which was held in `a` at that time. Even when you later assign to `a` some other value like `a=3;` `b` would still hold its own copy of 1.

Comment: To update value of `head1` and let it reflect new data in `numberCounter` you need to reevaluate `" Multiplied by 2: " + numberCounter * 2` and assign its result to `head1` again after changing `numberCounter`.

Comment: `numberCounter` is being incremented in each iteration, but that is all what is inside the loop, so everything else is just executed once. You need a block and put all statements to be repeated inside it, together with the increment statement: `while (condition) { statement1; statement2; ... numberCounter = numberCounter + 1; }`

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in the comments, make sure your counter variable starts from 0 :

```
int numberCounter = 0;
while (numberCounter != 10) {
   System.out.println(numberCounter);
   numberCounter = numberCounter + 1; // or numberCounter++;
}
```

UPDATE

After you posted your full code, it seems clear that you expect that each iteration of your integer would change the value assigned to your Strings, eg `head2` & `head3`. **This is wrong**. At the point you initialized these String variables your integer was converted to a String inside that variable (since you used string concatenation). To see the effect of the iterated integer, you can add the below println statements inside your loop, eg :

```
while (numberCounter != 10) {
     numberCounter = numberCounter + 1;
     System.out.println(" Multiplied by 2: " + numberCounter * 2);
     System.out.println(" Multiplied by 10: " + numberCounter * 10);
}
```

Comment: I do have the number counter initialized to 0, I might have entered in something incorrectly, or the problem could be that I'm using an online compiler (work computer.) I just edited my question to include more code.

Comment: That did it! I'm still trying to wrap my head around how it was wrong, but I think I'm getting it. One minor note is that now the count is starting at 1, so I initialized numberCounter to -1 so I can multiply by 0 first. Outside of that, this method was perfect! Thanks, @funkyjelly!

Comment: @Edwin the proper way to see the 0 value effect of your integer would be to change the order inside the while loop : first do the prints (to see results for 0 value too) and then increment the value. Right now you first increment the value so you don't get to see the 0